# Error: error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have both VS 2012 and 2013 installed in my computer and for some projects need 2012 version. using `msbulid` in shell command I have the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found
```

Would you please let me know how could I change `msbuild` option to use VS 2013?
Please Do not ask me to uninstall the VS 2012 version, because it is crucial for some other projects.

Comment: What shell command did you use? Did you use the "Development Command Prompt" corresponding to the VS version you want or did you use the 2012 command prompt to build both versions? The paths and environment variables for each edition are different, you should use the proper command prompt for the version you want

Comment: msbuild.exe my.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=13.0?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using `cmd`. Because I am using it to call some other files to run then I have to use the windows command prompt. With "Development Command Prompt" works great but with `cmd` not!

Comment: `cmd` will use the system's path and environment which target the latest installed version. You don't have to use it though, the Development Command Prompt is simply a `cmd` that starts with the `VsDevCmd.bat` batch to set the variables and path. You can either call your tools inside the dev prompt, or call `VsDevCmd.bat` from any other command prompt to set the environment. Check the dev command prompt's target to see which batch is called by each version

Comment: Could I call the Development Command Prompt from `cmd`? As I told I need to call ``msbuild`` after some other commands that are all working in `cmd`. By the way VS 2013 is the latest installed version in my PC.

Comment: If you check the Dev prompt's shortcut you'll see that it simply starts a new `cmd` with the proper `VsDevCmd.bat`. So, you can run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` for 2013 or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` for 2012, from any command prompt